# ¿como puede reagrupar mi respuesta JSON en un nuevo arreglo en javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, foreach

ejemplo:

```
{
    "Artefactos-IQT": {
        "Total": 2550515.34,
        "Detalle": {
            "1": {
                "Total": 80473.0
            },
            "2": {
                "Total": 70305.0
            },
            "3": {
                "Total": 68033.0
            },
            "4": {
                "Total": 90507.0
            },
            "5": {
                "Total": 29038.0
            }
        }
    },

  "Artefactos 1-PCL": {
  ...
  }
}
```

teniendo en cuenta que la primeroa informacion es tienda y luego estas sus otros datos hasta que vuelte a recorrer nuevamente la tienda y quiseira separar este arreglo en 2 formas distintas:

```
"Detalle": {
            "1": {
                "Total": 80473.0
            },
            "2": {
                "Total": 70305.0
            },
            "3": {
                "Total": 68033.0
            },
            "4": {
                "Total": 90507.0
            },
            "5": {
                "Total": 29038.0
            }
        }
```

convertir la informacion del detalle a un arreglo de la siguiente forma:

detalle = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

como segundo arreglo es un poco mas complejo pero quisiera tener uno del datasets para un grafico de chart js de la siguiente forma:

```
artefacto = [
                {
                    label: 'Artefactos-IQT',
                    data: [80473.0, 70305.0, 68033.0, 90507.0, 29038.0], // Totales del detalle
                    backgroundColor: "blue",
                    borderColor: "lightblue",
                    fill: false,
                    lineTension: 0,
                    radius: 5
                },
                 {
                    label: 'Articulo 01',
                    ...
                },
            ]
```

---

muchas gracias por su ayuda pero cuando intento probra el codigo con el formato de JSON de obtendo desde mi controlador PYTHON es de la siguiente forma y obtengo este resultado:

```js
let json = {
  "Artefactos-YMS": {
    "Total": 338356.0,
    "Detalle": {
      "1": {
        "Total": 587827.0
      },
      "2": {
        "Total": 635988.1
      },
      "3": {
        "Total": 697516.5
      },
      "4": {
        "Total": 581277.0
      },
      "5": {
        "Total": 410221.1
      }
    }
  },
  "Artefactos-IQT": {
    "Total": 2550515.34,
    "Detalle": {
      "1": {
        "Total": 587827.0
      },
      "2": {
        "Total": 635988.1
      },
      "3": {
        "Total": 697516.5
      },
      "4": {
        "Total": 581277.0
      },
      "5": {
        "Total": 410221.1
      }
    }
  },
}
let lista = JSON.parse(json)

function GetIDLista(lista, tienda) {
  return Object.keys(lista[tienda].Detalle);
}

function GetDataset(lista, tienda) {
  return Object.entries(lista[tienda].Detalle).map(e => e[1].Total);
}

console.log(GetIDLista(lista, "Artefactos-IQT"))
console.log(GetDataset(lista, "Artefactos-IQT"))
```

alguna subjerencia para el ejercicio si es que me pueden apoyar soy nuevo en JAVASCRIPT

Comment: Lecturas recomendadas:  [ask], [tour] y [example]. Tu pregunta no parece una pregunta, sino más bien una tarea que nos encomiendas realizar. Es probable que termine cerrada, lo siento.

Comment: Si, si no muestras tu esfuerzo no esperes que nos esforzemos por ti. Para tu objetivo puedes leer acerca de `Object.entries()` o `Object.keys()`. Saludos

Comment: sino deseas apoyar, es mas facil no comentar por que uno pregunta por que no conoce y queremos aprender mas y como se aprende con ejemplos.

Comment: Este no es una escuela de programación. Este es un sitio de preguntas y respuesta sobre programación; se supone que ya sabes programar pero te has topado con un problema específico.

Comment: Se aprende con ejemplos, pero [es.so] _ni es un sitio de tutoriales, ni es un repositorio de código_. Es por eso que debes mostrar un [repro] _de lo que has intentado_ y el problema _específico_ que has tenido. Como te han dicho, lee [ask].

Comment: claro es facil decir las cosas sin la menor intension de apoyar que es lo que busco y no necesito un tutorial solo un ejemplo para poder realizar lo que se necesita pero si no saben como hacer se entiende al menos yo si intento aprender nuevas formas de trabajar con javascript y no me gusta estar estancado

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre crear 2 funciones

- GetIDLista retorna un array con las id's
- GetDataset retorna un array con los totales

Ambas reciben como parámetro la "lista" (el json ya convertido en objeto javascript) y además el nombre de la tienda.

```
function GetIDLista(lista, tienda) {
    return Object.keys(lista[tienda].Detalle);
}
function GetDataset(lista, tienda) {
    return Object.entries( lista[tienda].Detalle).map(e => e[1].Total);
}
```

Ejemplo:

```js
let json = `{
    "Artefactos-IQT": {
        "Total": 2550515.34,
        "Detalle": {
            "1": {
                "Total": 80473.0
            },
            "2": {
                "Total": 70305.0
            },
            "3": {
                "Total": 68033.0
            },
            "4": {
                "Total": 90507.0
            },
            "5": {
                "Total": 29038.0
            }
        }
    },
    "Artefactos 1-PCL": {
    "Total": 10,
        "Detalle": {
            "1": {
                "Total": 1
            },
            "2": {
                "Total": 2
            },
            "3": {
                "Total": 3
            },
            "4": {
                "Total": 4
            },
            "5": {
                "Total": 29038.0
            }
        }
    }
}`;
let lista = JSON.parse(json);

function GetIDLista(lista, tienda) {
    return Object.keys(lista[tienda].Detalle);
}
function GetDataset(lista, tienda) {
    return Object.entries( lista[tienda].Detalle).map(e => e[1].Total);
}


console.log(GetIDLista(lista, "Artefactos-IQT"));
console.log(GetDataset(lista, "Artefactos-IQT"));
```